# SimpleITK 3Deuler angles rotation volumetric data

Tags: python, orientation, direction, euler-angles, simpleitk

I want to rotate my volumetric CT data using the euler angles x, y and z. For this, I use SimpleITK. I have read the question from [Dr. Jessop - simpleitk-rotation-of-volumetric-data-e-g-mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171643/simpleitk-rotation-of-volumetric-data-e-g-mri) and I think I have the same problem that my orientation/direction is not an identity matrix. The direction namely is:

```
0.08716564279125966, 0.0, -0.9961938319005929, 0.9961938319005927, 6.633444000000004e-17, 0.08716564279125968, 0.0, -1.0, 6.12303124808918e-17
```

However, the solution Dr. Jessop has found is by using an axis-angle orientation so that he can rotate around the z axis only. I want to rotate around all axes by using Euler angles. How can I achieve this?

P.S. I would have commented on Dr.Jessops question to ask it, but I don't have enough reputation points for this.

The code of dr. Jessop:

```
# This function is from https://github.com/rock-learning/pytransform3d/blob/7589e083a50597a75b12d745ebacaa7cc056cfbd/pytransform3d/rotations.py#L302
def matrix_from_axis_angle(a):
    """ Compute rotation matrix from axis-angle.
    This is called exponential map or Rodrigues' formula.
    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array-like, shape (4,)
        Axis of rotation and rotation angle: (x, y, z, angle)
    Returns
    -------
    R : array-like, shape (3, 3)
        Rotation matrix
    """
    ux, uy, uz, theta = a
    c = np.cos(theta)
    s = np.sin(theta)
    ci = 1.0 - c
    R = np.array([[ci * ux * ux + c,
                   ci * ux * uy - uz * s,
                   ci * ux * uz + uy * s],
                  [ci * uy * ux + uz * s,
                   ci * uy * uy + c,
                   ci * uy * uz - ux * s],
                  [ci * uz * ux - uy * s,
                   ci * uz * uy + ux * s,
                   ci * uz * uz + c],
                  ])


# This is equivalent to
# R = (np.eye(3) * np.cos(theta) +
#      (1.0 - np.cos(theta)) * a[:3, np.newaxis].dot(a[np.newaxis, :3]) +
#      cross_product_matrix(a[:3]) * np.sin(theta))

return R



def resample(image, transform):
   """
   This function resamples (updates) an image using a specified transform
   :param image: The sitk image we are trying to transform
   :param transform: An sitk transform (ex. resizing, rotation, etc.
   :return: The transformed sitk image
   """
   reference_image = image
   interpolator = sitk.sitkLinear
   default_value = 0
   return sitk.Resample(image, reference_image, transform,
                        interpolator, default_value)


def get_center(img):
   """
   This function returns the physical center point of a 3d sitk image
   :param img: The sitk image we are trying to find the center of
   :return: The physical center point of the image
   """
   width, height, depth = img.GetSize()
   return img.TransformIndexToPhysicalPoint((int(np.ceil(width/2)),
                                             int(np.ceil(height/2)),
                                             int(np.ceil(depth/2))))

def rotation3d(image, theta_z, show=False):
    """
    This function rotates an image across each of the x, y, z axes by theta_x, theta_y, and 
    theta_z degrees
    respectively
    :param image: An sitk MRI image
    :param theta_x: The amount of degrees the user wants the image rotated around the x axis
    :param theta_y: The amount of degrees the user wants the image rotated around the y axis
    :param theta_z: The amount of degrees the user wants the image rotated around the z axis
    :param show: Boolean, whether or not the user wants to see the result of the rotation
    :return: The rotated image
    """
    theta_z = np.deg2rad(theta_z)
    euler_transform = sitk.Euler3DTransform()
    print(euler_transform.GetMatrix())
    image_center = get_center(image)
    euler_transform.SetCenter(image_center)

    direction = image.GetDirection()
    print(direction)
    axis_angle = (direction[2], direction[5], direction[8], theta_z)
    np_rot_mat = matrix_from_axis_angle(axis_angle)
    euler_transform.SetMatrix(np_rot_mat.flatten().tolist())
    resampled_image = resample(image, euler_transform)
    if show:
        slice_num = int(input("Enter the index of the slice you would like to see"))
        plt.imshow(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(resampled_image)[slice_num])
        plt.show()
    return resampled_image
```

To get the rotationmatrix from the euler angle method, this code could be used:

```
    def matrix_from_euler_xyz(e):
        """Compute rotation matrix from xyz Euler angles.
        Intrinsic rotations are used to create the transformation matrix
        from three concatenated rotations.
        The xyz convention is usually used in physics and chemistry.
        Parameters
        ----------
        e : array-like, shape (3,)
            Angles for rotation around x-, y'-, and z''-axes (intrinsic rotations)
        Returns
        -------
        R : array-like, shape (3, 3)
             Rotation matrix
        """
        alpha, beta, gamma = e
        # We use intrinsic rotations
        Qx = matrix_from_angle(0, alpha)
        Qy = matrix_from_angle(1, beta)
        Qz = matrix_from_angle(2, gamma)
        R = Qx.dot(Qy).dot(Qz)
        return R
```

However, the orientation should still be incorporated. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This can be performed using SimpleITK using Euler3DTransform and passing it into the resampleitkfilter, which I believe is what this code is doing.

For adding in directions -> GetDirection() will return a unit direction matrix/cosines. I.e an identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it (with the help of zivy from the [itk discourse](https://discourse.itk.org/t/simpleitk-euler3d-transform-problem-with-output-size-resampling/4387)

My answer is this:

```
# The function which is used to rotate (and make the 3D image isotropic) using euler angles
def rotation3d(image, theta_x, theta_y, theta_z, output_spacing = None, background_value=0.0):
    """
    This function rotates an image across each of the x, y, z axes by theta_x, theta_y, and theta_z degrees
    respectively (euler ZXY orientation) and resamples it to be isotropic.
    :param image: An sitk 3D image
    :param theta_x: The amount of degrees the user wants the image rotated around the x axis
    :param theta_y: The amount of degrees the user wants the image rotated around the y axis
    :param theta_z: The amount of degrees the user wants the image rotated around the z axis
    :param output_spacing: Scalar denoting the isotropic output image spacing. If None, then use the smallest
                           spacing from original image.
    :return: The rotated image
    """
    euler_transform = sitk.Euler3DTransform (image.TransformContinuousIndexToPhysicalPoint([(sz-1)/2.0 for sz in image.GetSize()]), 
                                             np.deg2rad(theta_x), 
                                             np.deg2rad(theta_y), 
                                             np.deg2rad(theta_z))

    # compute the resampling grid for the transformed image
    max_indexes = [sz-1 for sz in image.GetSize()]
    extreme_indexes = list(itertools.product(*(list(zip([0]*image.GetDimension(),max_indexes)))))
    extreme_points_transformed = [euler_transform.TransformPoint(image.TransformContinuousIndexToPhysicalPoint(p)) for p in extreme_indexes]
    
    output_min_coordinates = np.min(extreme_points_transformed, axis=0)
    output_max_coordinates = np.max(extreme_points_transformed, axis=0)
    
    # isotropic ouput spacing
    if output_spacing is None:
      output_spacing = min(image.GetSpacing())
    output_spacing = [output_spacing]*image.GetDimension()  
                    
    output_origin = output_min_coordinates
    output_size = [int(((omx-omn)/ospc)+0.5)  for ospc, omn, omx in zip(output_spacing, output_min_coordinates, output_max_coordinates)]
    
    output_direction = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
    output_pixeltype = image.GetPixelIDValue()

    return sitk.Resample(image, 
                         output_size, 
                         euler_transform.GetInverse(), 
                         sitk.sitkLinear, 
                         output_origin,
                         output_spacing,
                         output_direction,
                         background_value,
                         output_pixeltype)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be performed using SimpleITK using VersorRigid3DTransform and passing it into the resampleitkfilter, which I believe is what this code is doing in a way.

I would suggest using scipy.transform.rotation module to pass in a versor into the rigid3Dtransform then set your direction from the input to output accordingly.

I 'think' this will work even with your off-unit directions but as always with 3D affine transforms this might be missing something that brighter mathematicians can critique:

```py
    r = R.from_euler('zyx', [90, 45, 30], degrees=True)
    orientation = r.as_quat()

    transform = sitk.VersorRigid3DTransform()
    translation = sitk.TranslationTransform(3, (x,y,z))
    transform.SetTranslation(translation.GetOffset())
    #get rot_center from your center of image function as tuple (x,y,z)
    rotation = sitk.VersorTransform([orientation[0], orientation[1], orientation[2], orientation[3]],rot_center)
    transform.SetRotation(rotation.GetVersor())
    transform.SetCenter(rotation.GetCenter())

    size = img.GetSize()
    bounds = list()
    for x in [0, size[0]]:
        for y in [0, size[1]]:
            for z in [0, size[2]]:
                bounds.append(img.TransformIndexToPhysicalPoint((x, y, z)))

    # get the physical position of the bounds given transform
    trans_bounds = list()
    for b in bounds:
        trans_bounds.append(transform.TransformPoint((b[0], b[1], b[2])))
    trans_bounds = np.array(trans_bounds)

    xmin = np.min(trans_bounds.T[0])
    xmax = np.max(trans_bounds.T[0])

    ymin = np.min(trans_bounds.T[1])
    ymax = np.max(trans_bounds.T[1])

    zmin = np.min(trans_bounds.T[2])
    zmax = np.max(trans_bounds.T[2])

    output_origin = (xmin, ymin, zmin)

    res_all = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    res = res_all[0]
    output_size = np.array(
        [int(np.round((xmax - xmin) / res)), int(np.round((ymax - ymin) / res)), int(np.round((zmax - zmin) / res))])
    output_size = output_size.astype(int)


    resampleFilter = sitk.ResampleImageFilter()
    resampleFilter.SetTransform(transform.GetInverse())
    resampleFilter.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkLinear)
    resampleFilter.SetSize(output_size.tolist())
    resampleFilter.SetOutputOrigin(output_origin)
    resampleFilter.SetOutputSpacing(res_all)
    resampleFilter.SetOutputDirection(img.GetDirection())
    resampleFilter.SetDefaultPixelValue(0.0)
```